# Text file averages in Python with different weighted grades

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to open a text file in python that holds the names of people and grades from specific tests they took. These grades are also accompanied by the test weight.

For example:

```
Billy Bother 20 89 30 94 50 82
Hermione Heffalump 40 93 60 97
Kurt Kidd 20 88 30 82 40 76 10 99
```

The first number is the weight, while the second number is the grade, and this pattern continues through the file.

To calculate the `average` I need to use `((w1 * g1) + (w2 * g2) + ... + (wn * gn)) / 100`, where `w = weight` and `g = grade`.

I have no idea how to set up the code to make this work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `with open('my_text_file.txt', 'r') as f: for line in f: print(line)`. To extract specific values, you can use `split()` on each line. Google those things and read stackoverflow rules (on this account as well).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is a school assignment, so I will just give an outline of how to approach it, rather than writing a solution for you.

You will need to find out how to:

1. Read a text file and loop over the lines, so each line becomes a string of text
2. For each line, split it into fields (Billy, Bother, 20, ...)
3. Pull out the first two fields - these are the names
4. Loop over the rest of the fields, reading two at a time (w,g)
5. Multiply w * g and add the result to a total
6. Once all the numbers are processed, divide by 100

You should be able to find solutions to all of these sub-problems in a Python tutorial, book, Internet search or Stack Overflow - but if not, come back and ask a more specific question, showing your attempted code and the problem you are having with it.